# Failed to read JSON file in new IDE

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I have an Eclipse project with the following code:

```
import org.json.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

(...)

public static void main( String[] args )
{   
String resourceName = "C:\\Users\\Snail_Sniffer\\Desktop\\books.json";
String jsonData = readFile(resourceName);   
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
(...)
```

It produces no errors and works as intended, but when I reuse the same code in IntelliJ, it produces following errors:

> Error:java: constructor JSONObject in class org.json.simple.JSONObject
>   cannot be applied to given types;
>         required: no arguments
>         found:    java.lang.String
>         reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

> Error:java: cannot find symbol
>         symbol:   method getString(java.lang.String)
>         location: variable jobj of type org.json.simple.JSONObject

**What is causing the issue and how to workaround it?**

Comment: do you have valid JSON in file?

Comment: Yes, it's working in eclipse IDE

Comment: Looks like a version conflict. How do you handle your dependency for org.json.*? Do you use a package manager like maven or gradle?

Comment: @Sma Ma I've downloaded json-simple-1.1.jar and added it via File->Project structure-> Modules->Dependancies.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved. I've checked the dependancies again.and I've simply deleted the  json-simple-1.1.jar. It's working as intended now.

Comment: Maybe there is a other version of that class in your classpath. Add java depencies like your way is not the best way. My recomendation is to use a java package manager to avoid errors like that. For example maven. Is this a option for you?

Comment: @Sma Ma I'll jave to look deeper into this, maybe with some tutorials. Currently, I don't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which library you are using in eclipse, but [org.json.simple.JSONObject](http://miamarti.github.io/HorusFramework/javadoc/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html) does not have constructor with `String` argument. It has only no argument constructor

```
public JSONObject()
```

If you want to parse json string  using `org.json.simple` library you need `JSONParser`

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonData);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I might have different libraries. I've replaced the last line with the suggested two, but it produces 'java cannot find symbol' error.

Comment: You need to import that class @Ambu

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to arrive at the solution. Problem is solved, it was issue with dependencies, I'm not using org.json.simple anymore, probably.